# Save state parameters on ui-sref link

Tags: angular-ui-router, ui-sref

### The situation

There are 2 sub states using the same parameter:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('rootState', {
        url: '/{ID}',
        templateUrl: 'template1.html',
        controller: 'controller1',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .state('rootState.subStateA', {
        url: '/subStateA',
        parent: 'rootState',
        templateUrl: 'template2.html',
        controller: 'controller2',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .state('rootState.subStateB', {
        url: '/subStateB/',
        parent: 'rootState',
        templateUrl: 'template3.html',
        controller: 'controller3',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
```

Now, there are 2 links:

```
<a href ui-sref="rootState.subStateA">State A</a>
<a href ui-sref="rootState.subStateB">State B</a>
```

### The problem

When I move from State A to State B the parameter ID become null.

### The question

How can I keep the ID parameter while moving from one state to another?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to inject $stateParams into $rootScope and have them everywhere:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

And later you can use this links:

```
<a href ui-sref="rootState.subStateA({ID:$stateParams.ID})">State A</a>
<a href ui-sref="rootState.subStateB({ID:$stateParams.ID})">State B</a>
```

Or maybe even

```
<a href ui-sref="rootState.subStateA($stateParams})">State A</a>
<a href ui-sref="rootState.subStateB($stateParams})">State B</a>
```